# How can I settle both 'next and previous' buttons in pagination

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I wanna it to be like this:

[image]

But not like this:

[image]

I tried to solve this issue but no way, if anyone know please help: This is my render code in react.js:

```
return (
    <nav className="">
      <ul className="pagination"> 
      {PageNumbers.includes(currentPage - 1) && 
            <a className="prev page-link" href="!#" onClick={() => { setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);   paginate(currentPage - 1); }}> Previous
             </a>}     
       {PageNumbers.map(number => (          
           (number < 3 || (number > currentPage-2 && number < currentPage+2) || 
              number > PageNumbers.length - 2 )  ?
          <li
             key={number}
             className={number === currentPage ? "page-item active" : "page-item "}
          >
            <a
              onClick={() => paginate(number)}
              href="!#"
              className="page-link"
            >
               {number}
            </a>
         </li>
         :
         PageNumbers.length>5 && number < 4 ? '...'
         : 
         number < PageNumbers.length && number == currentPage+2 ? '...'
         :null

     ))}

        {PageNumbers.includes(currentPage + 1) && 
        <a className="next page-link" href="!#" onClick={() => {setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1); paginate(currentPage + 1); }}> Next 
        </a>}  
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

);
}

Comment: Sorry--I'm not really clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "settle" buttons? Do you mean that `[Previous]` is not appearing but it should? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, exactly previous should be appeared and also the same for next button. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can understand, you would like to always show the previous button, and to show it as disabled when a user is on the first page.

Your current logic for the previous button is:

```
{PageNumbers.includes(currentPage - 1) && 
  <a 
    className="prev page-link"
    href="!#"
    onClick={() => { 
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
      paginate(currentPage - 1); }}
  > 
    Previous
  </a>
}
```

This means that if the list of page numbers includes the previous page (page - 1), show the button, otherwise hide it.

So if you remove the conditional, you will always show the Previous Button.

Now if we want to add a disabled class, you will need to use a disabled rule in CSS like this for instance:

```
.paginate-disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: light-gray;
}
```

Now we want to conditionally add the CSS class and disable the link/button if we are on the first page.  So we can change the Previous button logic to the following:

```
<a 
  className={`${currentPage === 1 ? 'paginate-disabled' : ''} prev page-link`}
  disabled={currentPage === 1}
  href="!#"
  onClick={() => { 
    setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
    paginate(currentPage - 1); 
  }}
> 
  Previous
</a>
```

**Edit #1**

I am not sure why you are still able to click Previous when it is disabled, but you could try updating your onClick function like this:

```
  onClick={() => this.handleClickPrevious(currentPage)}
```

and defining your handleClickPrevious like this (it would be better to do this with state handlers):

```
handleClickPrevious = (currentPage) => {
  if (currentPage === 1) {
    return;
  }

  setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
  paginate(currentPage - 1);
};
```

You could also try modifying your onClick function to something like this:

```
    onClick={() => {
      if (currentPage > 1) {
        setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
        paginate(currentPage - 1); }}
      }
    }
```

**Edit #2**

Next Pagination... You should be able to use the logic from the previous button to adapt this code in a similar way.

```
<a 
  className={`${currentPage === PageNumbers.length - 1 ? 'paginate-disabled' : ''} next page-link`}
  disabled={currentPage === PageNumbers.length - 1}
  href="!#"
  onClick={() => this.handleClickNext(currentPage)}
> 
  Next
</a>

handleClickNext = (currentPage) => {
  if (currentPage === this.state.PageNumbers.length - 1) {
    return;
  }

  setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  paginate(currentPage + 1);
};
```

Comment: It's working wrong in previous button, in your last one code, when I cotninue click, who is about prev-disabled,  it's showing an empty value, what is the problem you think?

Comment: It shouldn't show anything if you click previous on the first page - it shouldn't be clickable in the first place.  Can you elaborate more on what is going wrong?

Comment: When I continue clicking back on prev button, while it's should be stop on number one, first it shows an empty pages, and also when I continue clicking back after null pages, it shows pages with data. I want it stop on number one and also stop with no more than existing pages, could you please help me with this, i'm going to be mad because of it. Thanks in advanced

Comment: See edit... the button should not be able to be clicked if it is disabled.  You could try using a real <button> instead of an anchor <a>.

Comment: I'm sorry man, it's working just with previous button but not with next. Could you please write next code? Thanks in advanced

Comment: It's working with previous button but not with next: this is next button:         
 <button className="page-link" href="!#" onClick={() => 
                    {setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1); 
                    paginate(currentPage + 1); }}> Next 
   </button>}

Comment: I updated the post, the logic is very similar to the previous logic.  You just need to do your comparisons off of PageNumbers.length.

Comment: It's working very good but still the last page(number 10). Stop on 9 and unable to continue to last one number 10. I'm going to be mad because of this pagination 